# How to create more edittext fields in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android project. I need to create some fields like the following image.

Here I am showing only 4 columns but I have 8 to 10 columns.
In one way I can generate edit texts dynamically.
How can I create these fields in android screen?

Comment: Please explain why you cant use table layout. IMO, table layout is the best option.

Comment: "Please suggest me if there is any other better way." Redesign your UI for mobile / touchscreens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you may use the TableLayout,TextView and EditText as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

   >
        <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>            
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="Location"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="Name"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:text="Age"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Gender"
     android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </TableRow>
         <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
             <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>            
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:layout_weight="1"/>
         </TableRow>
           <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
             <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="2"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>            
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:layout_weight="1"/>
         </TableRow>
          <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
             <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="3"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>            
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:layout_weight="1"/>
         </TableRow>
          <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
             <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="4"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>            
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:layout_weight="1"/>
         </TableRow>
          <TableRow android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
             <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="5"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>            
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

     android:layout_weight="1"/>
         </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make ListView with 4 EditTexts as row of your table. Count of rows would be generated automatically by ListView.